# How to access 'this' with setinterval

Tags: javascript

I tried to access 'this' after the implement of setinterval function, but couldn't access this from the function. Illustrated as below:

```
apple:'apple',
orange:'orange',
pie:'pie',
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(this.print(),100);
},
print:function(){
    console.log('print '+ this.apple + ' - ' + this.orange + ' - ' + this.pie);
}
```

**Output**: undefined

If I pass in the this as parameter for the function, the interval only called once and stop.

```
apple:'apple',
orange:'orange',
pie:'pie',
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(this.print(this),100);
},
print:function(self){
    console.log('print '+ self.apple + ' - ' + self.orange + ' - ' + self.pie);
}
```

**Output**: print apple - orange - pie (stopped after that)

How would I able to access the 'this' variables, after I called setinterval?

Here's the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/bwB9W/18/).

Comment: A missing ' after orange is breaking the colouring of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(_.bind(this.print, this), 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwB9W/21/

Comment: The point here is that when `setInterval` calls your function, it does not set `this`. If you want `this` set to a particular value, you need to set it explicitly via `bind`. See [the `this` problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#The_%27this%27_problem).

Comment: @RaymondChen true but to be fair, when you pass a function to another function, they cannot know what context to use when calling your callback unless they support passing it explicitly. This applies to anything that takes a callback.

Comment: Is _ a native javascript object? It's hard to google it because it is a symbol. Do you guys have any references about that _.bind method?

Comment: @pagliuca you can just use [`this.print.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) I am using underscore because the OP's jsfiddle has underscore the library included

Comment: @pagliuca. _ is a shorthand for using underscore js.

Comment: I don't think you can rebind a function once bound though. At least I think I remember reading something like that on MDN.

Answer (score 3):

use an anonymous function to call the function using self variable that will make sure that the function will be called with the scope of self so you can directly access variables using this

```
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() { self.print() },100);
},
print:function(){
    console.log('print '+ this.apple + ' - ' + this.orange + ' - ' + this.pie);
    //console.log(apple);
    //console.log(apple);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHqk6/2/

Comment: thanks for reply but your example only run once and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an anonymous function.

```
apple:'apple',
orange:'orange',
pie:'pie',
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval( function() { self.print() },100);
},
print:function(){
    console.log('print '+ this.apple + ' - ' + this.orange + ' - ' + this.pie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today but found a good explanation on mozilla.org explaining **the this problem** and a different solution:

From
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval#The_.22this.22_problem

> Explanation
>
> Code executed by setInterval() is run in a separate execution context
>   to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this
>   keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global)
>   object, it will not be the same as the this value for the function
>   that called setTimeout. See the following example (which for praticity
>   uses setTimeout() instead of setInterval() – the problem in fact is
>   the same for both timers):

And they had a solution there that worked for me

> A possible solution
>
> A possible way to solve the "this" problem is to replace the two
>   native setTimeout() or setInterval() global functions with two
>   non-native ones which will enable their invocation through the
>   Function.prototype.call method. The following example shows a possible
>   replacement:

```
// Enable the passage of the 'this' object through the JavaScript timers

var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout, __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;

window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};

window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};
```